# Rails 3 limiting is messing up ordering in database query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im using the will_paginate gem and rails 3.2.3.
Im trying to display all the posts that have certain tags ordered by the latest post so I use this:

```
  @posts = Post.find_by_post_type_label(session[:current_post_type],@selected_labels)
             .paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "comments.created_at DESC").all
```

but it returns the posts out of order. Each page will be sorted, but the second page will have posts that should have been on the first one.

Example:

```
Post.find_by_post_type_label(1,[])
```

returns posts [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] with each ones latest comment being that many months ago. The sql it generates is:

```
 SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `post`.`post_type_id` = 1
```

and

```
 SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` IN ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 ) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

If I order it, and limit it though, like:

```
Post.find_by_post_type_label(1,[]).order(comments.created_at DESC).limit(5)
```

which is how the will_paginate does it, it returns posts 2,3,4,5,7

after generating this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `post`.id FROM `posts` LEFT OUTER JOIN
`comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `post`.`id` WHERE 
`post`.`post_type_id` = 1 ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

and

```
 SELECT `post`.`id` AS t0_r0, `post`.`user_id` AS t0_r1, `post`.`name` AS 
 t0_r2, `post`.`image_id` AS t0_r3, `post`.`post_type_id` AS t0_r4, 
`post`.`description` AS t0_r5, `post`.`featured` AS t0_r6, `post`.`approved`
AS t0_r7, `comment`.`id` AS t1_r0, `comments`.`post_id` AS t1_r1, 
`comments`.`image_id` AS t1_r2, `comments`.`edits` AS t1_r3, 
`comments`.`color` AS t1_r4, `comments`.`min_reputation` AS t1_r5, 
`comments`.`created_at` AS t1_r6, `comments`.`updated_at` AS t1_r7 FROM 
`post` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = 
`post`.`id` WHERE `post`.`post_type_id` = 1 AND `post`.`id` IN (2, 3, 
4, 5, 7) ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC
```

It is clearly limiting before it is ordering, but I cant figure out how to change that.
Any help would be appreciated

*Edit 1*

The relationships are like so:

```
Class Post
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post_type
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, order: 'created_at DESC'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :labels

Class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

Comments are the only ones with timestamps in the database. The first comment holds the created at time for the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winded up using this sql in a find_by_sql

```
SELECT  p1.*, iv.created_at FROM posts p1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT p2.id id, max(c.created_at) created_at FROM posts p2
            INNER JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p2.id
            GROUP BY p2.id)
iv ON p1.id=iv.id ORDER BY iv.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the method [find_by_sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql)

So you could re-write your query like this:

```
ts = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type_id = ? and id in (?) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5", session[:current_post_type], @selected_labels).paginate(:page => params[:page]).all
```

I'm not sure what @selected_labels is, also this sorts by the Post.created_at and not the comments, I'm not sure why you would want to sort the Posts by the Comments...do you want to see the most active posts first?

Comment: Selected labels is used by the find_by_type_label to filter posts. It was blank in my example. I want to show the posts with the most recent comments first. ordering by post attributes isnt causing problems for me, its only when I try to use the nested? attributes that the ordering starts occurring after the limit